# Displaying a precomputed trajectory problem

Tags: ros, rviz, plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I follow the instructions on [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/walk_msgs/Tutorials/Loading%20a%20precomputed%20trajectory) to plot trajectories in Rviz previously recorded from a .YAML file I get the following error: (add all sesion)

```
diego@ubuntu:~$ rosrun walk_msgs generator _yaml:=/home/diego/Descargas/dropping_the_ball.yaml
fatal error: yaml-cpp: error at line 7, column 3: key not found: left-hand
 [ERROR] [1362606276.617362117]: fatal error: yaml-cpp: error at line 7, column 3: key not found:     left-hand***
```

And don't show anything. Any sugestion?

I work on ROS FUERTE

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57335/displaying-a-precomputed-trajectory-problem/) by [DieGo_Cif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4369/diego_cif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry about the delay, I [pushed a fix (commit 6e514d0)](https://github.com/laas/humanoid_walk/commit/6e514d0c34fda9dec7419b40b67a424038540b0d) on master branch. It should be working now (pull, recompile and retest).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0